Uncountability of co-infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of infinite subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{N}\backslash A$ is also infinite. That is,
$$\mathcal{F} = \{ A\subset\mathbb{N}:A\text{ and } \mathbb{N}\backslash A \text{ are infinite} \}.$$
Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is uncountable.
I am trying to apply Cantor's Diagonalization Method, but I couldn't come up with any sequence that would do the trick.
Any hint is enough.

Let $S_1, S_2, \ldots \subset \mathbb N$ be a sequence of infinite, co-infinite sets. Take a sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $k$: $x_k \not \in S_k$ and $x_{k+1} \geq x_k + 2$. Now consider $S = \{x_k \mid k \geq 1\}$.

The +2 was the trick. Thanks a lot.

In the uncountable set $\wp(\Bbb N)$, the complement of $\mathcal F$ is countable, as the union of the two countable sets $\{A\subset\Bbb N\mid A\text{ is finite}\}$ and $\{A\subseteq\Bbb N\mid\Bbb N\setminus A\text{ is finite}\}$. Therefore, $\mathcal F$ is uncountable. It even has the same cardinality as $\wp(\Bbb N)$, i.e. the power of the continuum.

A much simpler approach. Thanks


There are only countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

So there are uncountably many infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Let $A$ be an infinite coinfinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$; e.g., the even integers.

Then $A$ has uncountably many infinite subsets. Any infinite subset of $A$ is co-infinite in $\mathbb{N}$.



@IgorSouza Think about the diagonal argument applied to sequences of $0$s and $1s$ that have $0$s in the odd components. The diagonal argument shows the set is uncountable, which lets you show the set you want is uncountable.

That was my first thought, but then I realized the argument was not quite complete: it only shows that $A$ (the set of even integers) has uncountably many subsets (finite or infinite).
